# Normalizr with Redux with nested array of objects

Tags: redux, react-redux, normalizr

I'm just getting started with using normalizr with Redux, and I can't make it work. *Even though I can do it with plain JavaScript.*

I have an array of objects

```
const data = [
  {
    data_detail: [
      {
        category: 'newCategory',
        _id: '123',
      },
    ],
    _id: 'abc_id',
    customer: {
      _id: '456',
      email: 'hello@gmail.com',
      name: 'Bob',
    },
    date: '2021-01-10T01:51:24.387Z',
  },
];
```

And I need to transform it to

```
const normalizedResponse = {
  customers: {
    '456': {
      _id: '456',
      email: 'hello@gmail.com',
      name: 'Bob',
    },
  },
  details: {
    '123': {
      category: 'newCategory',
      _id: '123',
    },
  },
  orders: {
   'abc_id: {
      order_detail: [123],
      _id: 'abc_id',
      customer: '456',
      date: '2021-01-10T01:51:24.387Z',
    },
  },
};
```

Step 1: Display just `orders`

What I do:

```
const userSchema = new schema.Entity(
  'orders',
  );

const userListSchema = new schema.Array(userSchema);


const normalizedData = normalize(data, userListSchema);
```

What I get

```
{
  "entities": {
    "orders": {
      "abc_id": {
        "data_detail": [
          {
            "category": "newCategory",
            "id": "123"
          }
        ],
        "id": "abc_id",
        "customer": {
          "id": "456",
          "email": "hello@gmail.com",
          "name": "Bob"
        },
        "date": "2021-01-10T01:51:24.387Z"
      },
      "abc_id-02": {
        "data_detail": [
          {
            "category": "newCategory1",
            "id": "123-02"
          }
        ],
        "id": "abc_id-02",
        "customer": {
          "id": "456-02",
          "email": "hello@gmail.com",
          "name": "Bob"
        },
        "date": "2001-01-10T01:51:24.387Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "result": [
    "abc_id",
    "abc_id-02"
  ]
}
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
 orders: {
   'abc_id: {
      order_detail: [123],
      _id: 'abc_id',
      customer: '456',
      date: '2021-01-10T01:51:24.387Z',
    },
  },
```

*The question:* How to remove some fields from orders and add new ones?

Comment: Yeah, there's really not enough info here to give any kind of an answer :)  We'd need to see what you've actually tried.

Comment: @markerikson sure :) I've added some normaliz code which I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 different entity types in your `data` object.  First draft out a `schema` for each of them:

```
const detail = new schema.Entity('details');

const customer = new schema.Entity('customers');

const order = new schema.Entity('orders');
```

Then go back and fill in the relationships.  It looks like `order` is the outermost entity.  An `order` contains an array of `details`/`categories` and a single `customer`.

```
const order = new schema.Entity('orders', {
  data_detail: [detail],
  customer,
});
```

All of your entities use `_id` instead of `id`, so you need to set the `idAttribute`.

Your `data` is an `array` of `order`.  You can use `new schema.Array(order)` but you can also just use `[order]`.

Here's your final code:

```
const customer = new schema.Entity("customers", {}, { idAttribute: "_id" });

const detail = new schema.Entity("details", {}, { idAttribute: "_id" });

const order = new schema.Entity(
  "orders",
  {
    data_detail: [detail],
    customer
  },
  { idAttribute: "_id" }
);

const normalizedData = normalize(data, [order]);
```

That gives you:

```
{
  "entities": {
    "details": { 
      "123": { 
        "category": "newCategory", 
        "_id": "123" 
        } 
      },
    "customers": {
      "456": { 
        "_id": "456", 
        "email": "hello@gmail.com", 
        "name": "Bob"
      }
    },
    "orders": {
      "abc_id": {
        "data_detail": ["123"],
        "_id": "abc_id",
        "customer": "456",
        "date": "2021-01-10T01:51:24.387Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "result": ["abc_id"]
}
```